# Docker exposed port unreachable

Tags: docker

I am running Node JS application on docker container. It is 100% working because if I run it without docker it works.

Problem is the exposed port 3002 doesn't work in browser. Nmap shows this port is available and opened but it doesn't work in browser.

I have the second app working on exposed port 3001 also through docker. This one does work. What could be the problem?

**EDIT**

Dockerfile:

```
# create a file named Dockerfile
FROM node:7.4.0-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g lab

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3002

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "2"
services:
  soho-api:
    build: .
    image: messenger-bot:0.1
    container_name: messenger-bot
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
```

deploy.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo docker stop messenger-bot
sudo docker rm messenger-bot
sudo docker rmi messenger-bot:0.1
sudo docker-compose build
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

I run from terminal: `bash deploy.sh`

Comment: let me see the Dockerfile and command for running a container

Comment: ok I'll edit the question

Comment: @BukharovSergey I've editted my question

Comment: Thank you @durisvk . The configuration looks good. i don`t saw a mistake. but i can suggest that node listens different port (not 3002), or expects different "Host" in request.

Comment: What does `docker-compose ps` say? It should tell you the port binding. And make sure nothing else is binding that port already. If you're on a remote Linux instance it's also possible something like iptables or ufw are filtering the port and need to be configured to open it.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Have you checked with nmap also with `sudo docker rmi messenger-bot:0.1 -f` done? Is possible that port was already busy in host and docker finds it already opened?

Comment: try putting JS on 3001 and see if it works